# Loop Through jQuery Datatable to get Particular Columns

Tags: jquery, loops, datatables

I'm trying to loop through the rows in my jQuery datatable to pull out certain row information and insert it into my array which I will later use in the AJAX call.

I understand I could use the `.each` in Datatables, but I only want some of the columns (I have HTML edit/delete that I don't need in the JSON)

The current set up is similar to:

```
//Create the array
var myArray = new Array();
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
var tableLength = oTable.fnGetData().length;

        //Step through table
        for (var i = 0; i < tableLength; i++) {
            myArray[i][0] = oTable.fnGetData(i, 0);
            myArray[i][1] = oTable.fnGetData(i, 1);
            myArray[i][2] = oTable.fnGetData(i, 3);
            myArray[i][3] = oTable.fnGetData(i, 4);
        }
//Stringify the object
jsonArray = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

Perhaps my syntax is off for `fnGetData`? The reference sheet does say the parameters are (row, node). Is this the correct way to step through this table getting only certain values?

Answer (score 4):

If you want only the n column:

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
var secondCellArray=[];
$.each( oTable.fnGetData(), function(i, row){
    secondCellArray.push( row[1]);
})
```

Alternative way... but you get the html inside a cell...
You can access all the rows using:

```
var rows = $("#myTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
//Get HTML of 3rd column (for example)
cells.push($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(3)").html()); 
}
```